# Replace with update in cassandra

Tags: node.js, replace, command-line, cassandra, table-plus

I wanto update string to another string with method replace.
I have been update success with MYSQL, but cassandra, I have a error.
Thank for all!

```
This is commandline with MySQL:
    update table_1
    set field_1 = replace(field_1, 'hello', 'bonjour') where user_id = 9999;
```

Answer (score 3):

@LiamNguyen, you would achieve that in Cassandra as follows:

```
UPDATE table_1
  SET field_1 = `bonjour`
WHERE user_id = 9999
  IF field_1 = 'hello';
```

Additional References:

- [UPDATE DML](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/cql/dml.html#update-statement)
- [Conditional updates](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_reference/cqlUpdate.html#cqlUpdate__conditionally-updating-columns)

p/s: I am assuming `user_id` is your primary key of that Cassandra table